# How to implement typing indicator in firebase in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show typing indicator in FIREBASE (objective c) when User1 write any message to User2. Please help me to provide code of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by simple set **Y** flag at **textViewDidBeginEditing** and make it **N** at **textViewDidEndEditing**  and on the observer, you can check if the value of Typing is yes or no by that you can update your design accordingly.

In the image below you can see that we have user thread we have updated the value of typing whenever the user starts typing or leave the text view

[image]

```
-(void)addTypingIndicator:(NSString *)typing {

     NSDictionary *dicts = @{ @"isFirstChatDone" : @"N",
                         @"readcount"   : @0,
                         @"status"      : @"member",
                         @"is_typing"   : typing
                         };

    [[self.usersData child:kCurrentUser.userid] setValue:dicts];
}

-(void)checkTyping {


    [DELEGATE.usersData observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if(snapshot.hasChildren){

        // check your typing key and update your design accordingly
    }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Knowing When a User is Typing` in the link below:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2